# Calling arbitrary function from pandas rolling series

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I can call an arbitrary method defined via a string variable on a pandas series. The way I would do it would be like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

method_name = 'mean'
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).__getattr__(method_name)()
```

Now I want to do the same with a rolling pandas series, the way I would do it would be like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

method_name = 'mean'
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).rolling(window=1).__getattr__(method_name)()
```

I get the following error when doing it:

```py
AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Is there a way to call an arbitrary method (mean, median, max, min, quantile) on a rolling pandas series?

Thanks!

Comment: pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).rolling(window=1).agg(method_name) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about **getattr** and **getattribute** from the Python documentation (Data Model): [**getattr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [**getattribute**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

The use of **getattribute** will solve your problem;

```
import pandas as pd

method_name = 'mean'
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).rolling(window=1).__getattribute__(method_name)()
```

> Output

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `__getattr__` must be implemented for each object. This is unlike `__getatrribute__` which is a method in the base `object` class in Python. When calling `__getatrr__`, you will get that object implementation of this method (if any). For `rolling`, the definition is below, which basically does some checking for caching/pickling purposes (the `_internal_names_set`), if not found, it checks the dataframe (the `self.obj`):

```
def __getattr__(self, attr: str):
    if attr in self._internal_names_set:
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
    if attr in self.obj:
        return self[attr]

    raise AttributeError(
        f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
    )
```

To avoid this, use the `getattr` builtin function:

```
>> getattr(df.rolling(3), 'mean')
```

I like `getattr` because it allows you to specify a third, optional argument for when the attribute is not defined:

```
>> getattr(df.rolling(3), 'mean', None)
```